# json gem can't be installed after fixing bcrypt_ext load error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, bcrypt, refinerycms, devkit

I'm trying to get my RefineryCMS site up and running and I'm catching a bcrypt_ext cannot load error when trying to register the first user. I have taken these steps

```
C:\> gem install --no-ri --no-rdoc bcrypt
C:\> cd (path to gems root)\bcrypt-3.1.7-x86-mingw32\ext\mri
C:\(path to gems root)\bcrypt-3.1.7-x86-mingw32\ext\mri> ruby extconf.rb
C:\(path to gems root)\bcrypt-3.1.7-x86-mingw32\ext\mri> make
C:\(path to gems root)\bcrypt-3.1.7-x86-mingw32\ext\mri> make install
```

which fixes the bcrypt_ext issue but now i'm unable to bundle install when asked to do so after trying to run rails server. Essentially I get native extension build errors after running devkitvars.bat to be able to use the make command. I'm stuck at this point and any help would be greatly appreciated.

- Running:

  - Windows 10 x64
  - Rails 4.2.5
  - Ruby 2.2.4
  - RefineryCMS 3.0.1
  - refinerycms-authentication-devise 1.0.4

Answer (score 0):

Try checkout the `bcrypt` [issue on github](https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby/issues/116). Look through the solutions that works for some user.

**Note**: If you're serious in learning Rails, I suggest you get a *nix box instead (or a VM). Rails and it's friends (Gems) has **NEVER** been friendly to Windows. Fiddling with Windows related issues will just slow you down in learning Rails.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up loading up a dual-boot of windows and Ubuntu. This project is working just fine now.